# Letter Arrangements of M,A,R,Y

Tags: probability-distributions

List all possible arrangements of the four letters m,a,r,and y. Let $\; C_1 \;$be the collection of the arrangements in which y is in the last position. Let $\; C_2\;$ be the collection of the arrangements in which m is the first position. Find the union and the intersection of $\; C_1\;$ and $\;C_2\;$.

Comment: The intersection looks like all words M _ _ Y. The union looks like all words of the forms _ _ _ Y and M _ _ _

Comment: You are asked to make a list. So make a list, say alphabetically. There will be $24$ arrangements, not too bad. Mark the ones that end in $y$ with a 1, and the ones that begin with m with a 2. Then you should not find it hard to list all of $C_1\cup C_2$, and (much easier) all of $X_1\cap C_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_1$={***MARY***,RAMY,ARMY,AMRY,**MRAY**,RMAY,}

So, n($C_1$)=3!=6

$C_2$=*{**MARY**,**MRAY**,MAYR,MYAR,MRYA,MYRA}*

So, n($C_2$)=3!=6

$C_1∩C_2$=**{MARY,MRAY}**  ; n($C_1∩C_2$)=2

$C_1UC_2$={***MARY***,RAMY,ARMY,AMRY,**MRAY**,RMAY,MAYR,MYAR,MRYA,MYRA} ; n($C_1UC_2$)=10.

Hope it helps.

Comment: looks like you have interchanged union and intersection..=) Thank you anyways!

Comment: Oh yeah, very sorry.-goin' to edit